# Are coarse-grained reconfigurable architectures a subset of dataflow architecture?

Tags: microprocessor, cpu, computer-architecture, processor, architecture

By definition, dataflow architectures consist of large modules in the dataflow path, such as adders and multipliers for integer, floating-point, or fixed-point computation.

Hence, are coarse-grained reconfigurable architectures a subset of dataflow architectures?

If not, how are coarse-grained reconfigurable architectures similar to and/or different from dataflow architectures?

Comment: They can be used as dataflow architectures but they can be used in other architectures too, so, no.